# How to add text to HTML input field on conditional statements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a percentage calculator and one of the features is displaying decrease/increase between two numbers. For example, if the user inputs 60 as the first num and 40 as the second, my code displays -33.33 but I also want it to display, in text, that there is an increase/decrease of "x" amount between numbers, depending on what the user has entered. Here's what my code looks like:

```
document.getElementById("calc1-submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const numX = document.getElementById("calc1-num-x").value;
  const numY = document.getElementById("calc1-num-y").value;
  const percentage = (numX / numY) * 100;
  document.getElementById("calc1-solution").value = percentage.toFixed(2);
});

document.getElementById("calc2-submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const numX = document.getElementById("calc2-num-x").value;
  const numY = document.getElementById("calc2-num-y").value;
  const percentage = (numX / 100) * numY;
  document.getElementById("calc2-solution").value = percentage.toFixed(2);
});

document.getElementById("calc3-submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const numX = document.getElementById("calc3-num-x").value;
  const numY = document.getElementById("calc3-num-y").value;
  const percentage = ((numY - numX) / numX) * 100;
  document.getElementById("calc3-solution").value = percentage.toFixed(2);
  
  
  function percentDiffer () {
      if (numX > numY) {
        
      }
  }

  

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use basic mathematics operations like this:

```js
  
function percentDiffer (numX, numY) {
      if (numX > numY) {
        return numX-numY;
      } else if (numY > numX) {
        return numY-numX;
      } else if (numX == numY) {
        return 0;
      }
  }

console.log(percentDiffer(10, 100));

console.log(percentDiffer(100, 10));

console.log(percentDiffer(10, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this:

```
document.getElementById("IncreseorDecrese").value = percDiff() //the id is just for reference

function percDiff(){
  let result;
    if (percentage > 0){
    result = 'increased of ' + percentage;
  } else{
    result = 'decreased of ' + percentage;
  }
return result
}
```